# AWS automated build and deploy pipeline for an AWS Lambda Function (already created)

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, cicd

If anyone can dumb this down for me, I will be soooo grateful.

**What I Currently Have**

I have an AWS Lambda function already set up. It is a python project in a docker container that is currently deployed by manually setting it up in the AWS Lambda web UI in AWS.

The docker container (used by the AWS Lambda function) currently is being pushed up from my local machine, to an AWS ECR repo, which is where the AWS Lambda is pulling the latest container from to deploy the latest lambda function.

This AWS Lambda function is run by a cron job every day, and it works. This whole function set up works. Yay.

**What I Want To Set Up**

I want to automate the process of:

1. Getting the latest code changes from a GitHub repo (preferably on commit to the master branch)
2. Running a docker build to create an image
3. Pushing the docker image to the AWS ECR repo I already have in place for my AWS Lambda function, and have it as the latest image
4. Set my AWS Lambda function to this latest image and deploy it so that the next time the cron job runs the AWS Lambda function, it will run the latest version of the app from Github.

I have seen questions pertaining to this flow/pipeline but they were written a few years ago and I know some big changes have come about with AWS SAM Pipeline (which I still find somewhat confusing) and the like.

Other tutorials talk about uploading the docker image to an S3 bucket. Why can't I upload it to an AWS ECR repo that I currently use? Can it be done?

Plus I think there are a few ways do to this - I've noticed CloudFormation, CodeDeploy, CodePipeLine, AWS SAM, ... What I don't understand is what is the best way? Do all of these technologies work together somehow? Do I need to use a SAM (serverless application model) - the yaml file seems endless with info that needs to be put in there - and commit it to my repo?

Can I set this build-deploy automation pipeline to update my currently working AWS Lambda funtion? or do I need to kinda start over?

What about the environment variables and the environment variables that are pulled from my secrets manager that is setup on the AWS Lambda function? Do I have to set them up again in the SAM .yaml file?

I was just hoping that I can still use the current AWS Lambda function/ AWS ECR setup that I currently have configured and just kinda add build-deploy actions around it. Is that wishful thinking?

Is it better/easier to create a Jenkins pipeline for this instead?

Thanks in advance. And yes, my head is spinning with all these questions and trying to decode the tutorials I have come across. I'm hoping someone can give me a better walk through.

===========================

EDIT:
I found this, which basically says that an AWS Lambda Application can do a build-deploy automation of an AWS Lambda function. I'm checking it out now.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/applications-tutorial.html

Comment: The S3 thing is for non-docker based Lambda functions as far as I understand. To answer your larger question, I would suggest taking those build and deployment steps you outlined and look for GitHub Actions that can perform each of those steps.

Comment: I may do that, but I was hoping to avoid using GitHub Actions - 1) my organization doesn't use GH Actions much so it can be overlooked when debugging/changing the pipeline, 2) I would like to keep this pipeline out of github so that if the repo was ever deleted, for whatever reason, and recreated under a different name, the pipeline itself would be intact.

maybe jenkins is the answer? our IT guys are super stingy about giving out service account credentials (understandably so), but it will be necessary for a jenkins pipeline.

Comment: Well you mentioned GitHub which is why I recommended Github Actions. That link you added to the question uses CloudFormation to setup AWS Code Pipeline and Code Build, which is exactly what I would suggest you look into since you don't want to use GitHub Actions.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. Crossing fingers this will work!